# CSS for WordPress plugins displays on some browsers, not others

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having problems with the CSS of two WordPress plugins: "WP Page Numbers" and "Image Caption." You can see the problems with both on this page:

http://www.dcbureau.org/category/national-security-news-service

The WP Numbers' functionality (horizontal list of page numbers at the end of articles loop) works fine, and the CSS style we've picked (panther) displays properly on Chrome 12.0.742.68 beta (Mac). But the CSS doesn't display at all on Firefox 4.0.1 or Safari 5.0.5 (also checked FF on Windows 7).

Same issue with Image Caption: functionality works, and caption displays properly on Chrome (pale gray background with white text) but not in the other browsers, where the caption box displays white.

Unfortunately my CSS skills are a bit limited so none of what I've tried has worked. I've already posted on WP.org but no replies yet. I would really appreciate any tips on how to solve these issues.

Thank you!

Luis

Comment: Dont see what the problem is. Both page numbers (Page: 1 2) at the bottom of the articles and the Heading Caption for the image at the top displays in IE9, FF4.0.1, GG11, AF5.0.5 and Opera 11 on windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to duplicate your problems on XP with FF 4.0.1, Chrome 11.0.696.65, IE8 or Safari 5.0.5.

Captions are displaying below the images with gray BG & black text in all browsers. And the pagination at the bottom all look and react similarly to each other.

Did you already resolve this on your own?

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't solved the issue before you guys tried, but this morning a friend suggested I put the CSS from the style sheet tied to that module in the header.php file, and that worked. I don't know why some people see the issue and others don't, but I think it's solved now. Thanks!